How to prevent erasing buffer content when an external program used in filter fails?
In the following example I use prettier but I am pretty sure the same happens when you filter with any external program that returns an error.
I am implementing a format on save feature but the buffer content is erased if prettier fails.
Here is my code:
g:null_device = '/dev/null'
var prettier_supported_filetypes = ['markdown', 'markdown.txtfmt', 'json', 'yaml']
def Prettify()
    # If prettier is not available, then the buffer content will be canceled upon
    # write
    if executable('prettier') && (index(prettier_supported_filetypes, &filetype) != -1)
        var win_view = winsaveview()
        exe $":%!prettier 2>{g:null_device} --prose-wrap always
                    \ --print-width {&l:textwidth} --stdin-filepath {shellescape(expand("%"))}"
        winrestview(win_view)
    else
      echom $"'prettier' is not installed OR '{&filetype}' filetype is not supported"
    endif
enddef

command! Prettify Prettify()

augroup PRETTIER
    autocmd!
    autocmd BufWritePre * if index(prettier_supported_filetypes, &filetype) != -1 | Prettify() | endif
augroup END

I cannot see eventual errors due to 2>{g:null_device}, but regardless, the current buffer content is erased if the prettier program ends with errors. How to prevent that?
EDIT: as a workaround I added the following code at the end of the Prettify() function, but there must be a better way to handle that:
if  line('$') == 1 && getline(1) == ''
  undo
  au! PRETTIER
  write
  echoerr "'prettier' returned errors, format on save is disabled"
endif


Get rid of that redirection and simply undo if v:shell_error is non-zero. Also, consider splitting the logic: the formatting part should be handled with gq and :help 'formatprg' or :help 'formatexpr'.

Thanks! Yes, I am aware of gq and I implemented a mechanism for autoformatting through gq in the past but, and I don't remember why, I reverted back to write functions as the above..

There's nothing wrong in using undo. Just test v:shell_error and throw an exception to prevent disk write.
%!foobar
if v:shell_error
    silent! undo
    throw "foobar failure"
endif


Thanks, but why the ´silent!` ?

@Barzi2001 I copied from my old plugin, so I only vaguely remember why. Perhaps, while having many filters applied one after another I had a problem when undo was called when no more undo states left. In that case undo can throw an exception by itself.
